# Docker container on ECS times out when communicating RDS Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs

I have a dockerized nodejs application on ECS which is supposed to connect to postgres instance located on Amazon RDS.

Locally, I am able to run the docker container and connect (read/write) to the RDS database

When I deploy the container to ECS, I get a timeout when trying to read/write to the RDS Postgres DB.

I built my docker container like so

`docker build -t my-app .`

I then ran my docker app

`docker run -p 80:3000 XXXXXXX`

My RDS instance is running at `myappdb.ceonhqpz1vl1.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/appdb`

I figured this must be a port issue, but I published the ports as stated above. So i figure this must work. But when I run the app through my browser on AWS and try to read/write to the DB, the request takes a long time and then times out.

I'm not sure where to debug at this point, I'm a bit new to docker

Comment: Did you ensure that the AWS security groups are configured properly to allow communication?

Comment: hmm, i have not. Can you point me to the right place where i can look in to that? Upon a quick search I see something about VPC. Should i be making sure that ECS/RDS are under the same VPC?

Comment: This depends on whether your instance of RDS is publicly accessible, but it would probably make sense for both to be in the same VPC.  Two machines within the same VPC still need their security group configured properly to ensure connectivity.

Comment: I made sure my RDS instance is publicly available. I am able to connect and read/write to my RDS instance when I run my docker container _locally_. I'm now confused as to whether i'm supposed to publish port `5432` on my docker container, so that external services like my RDC table can communicate.

Comment: thanks @Matthew, i figured out a solution through via Security Groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a setting for the RDS instance inbound traffic source that was set to my local IP; meaning that traffic to the Postgres RDS instance was limited to personal IP address. I changed it and it so the inbound traffic can be from `anywhere` or `0.0.0.0`. This is what I wanted for my use case.